# How do i get the last ID's from the inserted data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an option to send multiple rows into an table, i'm using an foreach to do that:

```
if (is_array($add['jobname'])) {
$insert = "INSERT INTO job_offers (job_category, status) VALUES ";

foreach ($add['job_name'] as $key => $value) {

$insertedval[] = "
('" . safe($add['job_category'][$key]) . "', 
 '" . safe($add['status'][$key]) . "')";

}
}
$insert .= implode($insertedval, ",");

$last_id = db_query($insert, '+id?'); //gets the last generated ID, its a function that i created, and working great.
```

The problem is that i want to get the last ID, and i'm getting, but i'm inserting multiple rows into the database, and i want to get the ID's from all the inserted values, because they are being sent at the same time.

I can't put the $last_id variable inside the foreach loop, what do i do?

ps: i'm using auto increment

Comment: no, you are totally wrong, i already have the last inserted id

Comment: out of curiosity, what's inside `safe()`?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string, Jack

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing reliable that you can do except inserting them one by one; you could use prepared statements to optimise that a little, but that's basically it.

Comment: I changed my code recently, because i was doing the full query inside the foreach loop, i changed because it seems dangerous, i was repeating INSERT INTO multiple times, am i right?

Comment: That depends on how you define dangerous.

Comment: I think that it can break the server, because i dont have a limit to insert multiple values, so, if someone tries to insert 20 rows at the same time, it would be dangerous, because the query is being repeated multiple times

Comment: I would equal the chances of breaking a server in that scenario as likely as rogue unicorn attacks.

Comment: You're going to want to look through [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187/812837), and some of the associated commentary.  Also, no RDBMS I'm aware of outputs multiple auto-gen ids, so you'd need to do this per-line (some do have a row-change table feature, but this isn't strictly for dealing with ids...)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this?

```
$db = new PDO("mssql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname, $user, $pass");
$db->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO job_offers (job_category, status) VALUES (?, ?)');

$insertedIds = array();
foreach ($add['job_name'] as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->execute($add['job_category'][$key], $add['status'][$key]));
    $id = $db->lastInsertId();
    array_push($insertedIds, $id);
}

$db->commit();
```

the ids should be in the insertedIds.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't.**

Only by saving the the last index id before the inserted data, and than do it again after and select all the ids between that range.

```
SELECT ID FROM job_offers ID BETWEEN last-before-insert AND last-after-insert
```

Comment: You'd have to wrap it inside a transaction, though ... and a master-master setup may cause issues as well; maybe locking the table ... :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom function to get the last insert id , there is already one built into both php mysqli and php PDO extensions .

As far I know , the last insert id is session aware , meaning you will get the last insert from the current insert requests only .

Get last inset id using PHP PDO

```
$pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Get last insert id using mysqli

```
$mysqli->insert_id;
```

$pdo and $mysqli are the connection variables